# Is there a way of adding JAXB custom annotations without using annox?

Tags: jaxb, annox

I've been struggling a lot past two days with the annox library, been almost on every google result and can't make it work. I just keep getting 'Unsupported binding namespace "http://annox.dev.java.net". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"' error.

I need to add an Annotation before an attribute in a class created in a xsd schema, does anyone knows if there's a way of doing this without using annox? Or how can I fix that error?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you describe your problem with annox in more detail? (Annox author here.)

Comment: ps. Here are sample projects for Ant and Maven: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22jaxb2-basics-sample-annotate%22.

Comment: Hi lexicore, sorry I couldn't answer you before, I had other priorities and could work on this until today. I downloaded the samples and make it work. I was missing something in the build.xml as some libraries. Thank you so much for the help.